# PHP + cURL + session id

Tags: php, session, curl

After googling for hours trying to find an answer for my problem I hope someone on SE can give me an answer.

I am trying to parse some PDF files from a website, the format of the URL looks like this: example.com/?s=ef6d225b80c0c590da26dcf1e37bc02c&t=2-1-2014%2013:24:25

I have no idea how I can fetch the session ID from this URL.

I tried something like this:

```
session_write_close();

$ch = curl_init($link); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie ); 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
session_id($_GET['session_id']);
print_r($_SESSION);
print(session_id());
But there is no output.
```

So what I need the session ID to pass into the URL and I have no idea how to do this.

I appreciate any help I can get about this issue. Thanks!

Comment: $_GET is for query strings in the url that invoked **YOUR** script. It has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with urls/data received from data you've fetched from some OTHER site via curl. Try http://php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from `$link`:

```
if (preg_match('~s=([a-f0-9]{32})~', $link, $match)) {
    // got the session id in $match[1]
}
```

Comment: So I fetched the URL and tried to open the PDF with a file_get_contents but it's not working. Should I use cUrl for this?

Here is the code:

    $html = file_get_html($baseURl . "/Acer-CR-6530/handleiding-5-100076.html');
    
    // find all link    
    foreach($html->find('a[rel=nofollow]') as $e) 
        $link = $e->href;
    $link = $baseURL . $link;
    echo file_get_contents($link);

Comment: Sorry about the format, I'm new to this site and couldn't find the proper formatting for a [code] block...