# file_get_contents not displaying product price

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I use file_get_contents in PHP.In the below code in URL works fine but price is not displaying.this is the ecommerce page url.In that page price and product inforamtion. i am trying to fetch the inforamation using file_get_contents function but price is not display in that page.

```
   $link = 'http://www.jkeats.com/search?q=kbu12';
   $violation = file_get_contents($link);
   print_r($violation);
```

Comment: did you check HOW that number gets added to the page? you're just assuming it's in the html. maybe it's added after page-load-completed with some JS code (e.g. ajax call).

Comment: You need to Parse the HTML for the specific HTML element that contains that Data. In this case the Price is inside <div title="59% savings"><p><b>THE PRICE</b></p></div>

Comment: @DirtyRedz i am trying but not geting any way to solve this probelm

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to do a couple of things...

you have the first part almost done, you have a product code and you fetch the page that contains the information.

On the page you fetch, your code is: kbu12  but that page makes an ajax call to a page: http://www.jkeats.com/getprice 
it is a POST request with a bunch of session headers and a variable named "item" with a value of: KR-S-KBU12

The new item code can be scraped off the initial page, but the price itself will need to come from a new call to the getprice page and your session parameters and "item" variable.  If you have access to all the "item" codes and how they map to your initial code "kbu12" it would help.

So to recap:

-get the html for the first page with the session/cookies.  you will need to use curl or a url fetching library.

-parse html to get new "item" code

-get html by POSTing (curl/library) to the getprice page and parse the result for your price.

Comment: i have not getting your point plz explain with example

Comment: @santosh  the code that you need to make to solve this problem is likely quite different from what you have and also lengthy.  Me giving you an example is basically doing your job for you and would take me about half and hour...mainly to deal with the session stuff and to figure out the parsing, etc..  K P described the reason why price cannot be parsed from the page you retrieve and I have outlined a path to follow in order to do your task. From here, search for "php curl session" and "parse html using php" which will give a great starting point. Also, the web-developer toolbar for ff.

Comment: @santosh  maybe this will be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885693/php-curl-session-id

Comment: thanks @ user1269942

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code on the site you are trying to pull from, you will see that the price section is being added via Javascript after the DOM is loaded. `<div class="pcell"> &nbsp; </div>` is being replaced with the price info. There is no way to get the price in PHP.